# морфемный разбор слова низменный

Tags: морфемика

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать по составу слово "низменный".

Спасибо!

Comment: Цитирую Грамоту.ру еще раз "Если нам удастся выяснить происхождение загадочного М, ответ будет дополнен. Спасибо за интересный вопрос". Специалисты считают вопрос интересным, а вот мы хотим его закрыть. Где же логика?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Практически все источники предлагают такой разбор: ***низ/менн/ый,*** где МЕНН – это суффикс.

Например, Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136317/менн](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136317/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD)

Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в имени прилагательном со значением отношения к тому или характеризуемости тем, что названо словом, от которого соответствующее имя прилагательное образовано (ни́зменный).

2. Вот что по этой теме пишет **Грамота.ру**

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=

Вопрос: Почему в слове "низменность" пишется 2 буквы "Н", как разобрать это слово **по составу** и, если корень "низм", а однокоренное слово "низина", откуда взялась **буква "М**"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Существительное ***низменность*** образовалось от прилагательного ***низменный***, от которого и было унаследовано две н. Написание нн в прилагательном можно объяснить двумя способами. Исторически низменный образовалось с помощью суффикса -енн- от вышедшего из употребления существительного ***низмя.***

Сейчас слово можно разобрать так: ***низ/менн/ость/***. Откуда появилось М, этимологические словари не дают ответа. В словаре В. Даля зафиксировано еще одно однокоренное слово с м – ***низмянка*** «низкорослый лесок по дурной почве; кустарный дрянной лес» и растение.

Если нам удастся выяснить происхождение загадочного М, ответ будет дополнен. Спасибо за интересный вопрос.

3. **Некоторые замечания по теме**

Прежде всего, кажется, что слово без М (низенный) – это нехарактерная **фонетика**  для русского языка, да и смысл не очень ясно прочитывается. Наращение основы с помощью сонорных гласных встречается часто (после гласных или согласных), мне кажется, что это в большей степени фонетический прием.

Любопытно отметить, что сочетание  ***ЗЕННЫЙ*** встречается в языке не часто, причем обычно в ударной позиции слов: *привезти – привезённый, ввезенный* (кроме *вывезенный*), *пронзить – пронзённый*.  Хотя есть и такие формы: *загрызть – загрызенный.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А как Вы считаете, не может ли М быть интерфиксом (асемантической прокладкой)?

Comment: Я думаю, что это так. Например,  об этом говорится в статье https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/interfiksatsiya-72148.html

Comment: С другой стороны,  это явление может иметь и семантические оттенки. К примеру, существовавшие ранее слова  «низмя, низмянка» были бы неясны без М, так что М можно посчитать  историческим суффиксом. В Толковом словаре словообразовательных единиц Ефремовой в статье о суффиксе ЕНН указано: - енн, также:  - евен, -ион, -менн, -ственн. Мы видим, что сюда включена и форма –ственн, которую можно рассматривать как сложный словообразовательный формант из двух суффиксов.